# Upgrading gcc (+jit) outside of any package manager help : What else to rebuild?

Tags: linux, upgrade, gcc, toolchain

Currently using [now-unsupported ggc 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/) on a Linux-5.4, I need to upgrade to at least gcc 10.

**A/** For whatever let's say *historical* reason, this upgrade must be carried on without relying on whatever package manager.
**B/** I do need the gcc to be built as a shared library (libgccjit.so) in order to enable [just in time compilation](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/JIT).

In this context, after having succeeded in the upgrade, :

**1/** should I (is it wise to) rebuild any other component of the toolchain (glibc ? libffi ? libtool ? binutils ?… ) with the newer gcc ?

**2/** Are there whatever other packages (other than those depending on the libgccjit.so) that I should rebuild entirely or take care not to rebuild in parts ?
(As an example (I do not know if this is still valid) there was a time when all qt-* components had to be built with the very same toolchain.)

Comment: Why is gcc 9 no longer supported? A link or simple explanation would be interesting.

Comment: @DanielMGessel : See https://gcc.gnu.org/ (supported releases 10,11,12…) ;-)

Comment: Ah, I see, it’s not a change to the kernel which requires a newer gcc. The ABIs should be stable as well as kernel interfaces - as long as struct layouts aren’t changing on you, it should all work…. It’s worth a spare machine to test on: compiler bugs happen, and latent bugs get exposed by new and different combinations of optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shouldn’t *need* to rebuild anything else, and given the manual nature of your maintenance I would avoid rebuilding anything I didn’t need to. Some tools do embed GCC paths, so you may want to rebuild those — this includes `libtool` in its default setup.
2. I’m not aware of any, apart from the kernel and any external modules you build on top of it. Even if there are sets of binaries requiring that they all be built with the same toolchain, the binaries you already have won’t need to be rebuilt unless you want to add a new one to the set (and then you’d need to rebuilt the whole set).

As evidence, I offer Debian, where new GCC uploads (including major version bumps) don’t result in rebuilding anything else, unless they introduce a library transition (a major soname bump on one of the GCC libraries), in which case packages which depend on the bumped library are rebuilt. On the wisdom of rebuilding side of things, [Fedora rebuilds everything](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_36_Mass_Rebuild) once the target toolchain for a given release is ready; but again for a manually-maintained setup this seems overkill.

Comment: Errr ? Not even at least the libtool script ? Mine appears to get paths to gcc hardcoded. grep gcc /usr/bin/libool -> … sys_lib_search_path_spec="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.4.0…" and many other lines with other occurrences.

Comment: Yes, even the `libtool` script. In Debian, GCC 10 became the default [in July 2020](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1161716/accepted-gcc-defaults-1188-source-into-unstable/), but `libtool` wasn’t rebuilt until [March 2021](https://buildd.debian.org/status/logs.php?pkg=libtool&arch=amd64) (because a new version was uploaded). If you examine your `libtool` in more detail, there’s a good chance that `compiler_lib_search_dirs` is never actually used, and ends up empty at the end of the script anyway. In Debian `sys_lib_search_path_spec` doesn’t include GCC paths, I don’t know if that’s special.

Comment: OK, paths are [removed during the `libtool` build](https://salsa.debian.org/mckinstry/libtool/-/blob/80abfa9a1a8517d9dd72a8036cf5a97da71f8c30/debian/rules#L126). Presumably your `libtool` should continue working if those paths disappear anyway.

Comment: When I was in industry we, and the OS supplier my team worked with, did full rebuilds more or less as frequently as possible (up to, and often including, backlogging QE). I don't have experience with any more laissez-faire approaches, but I can see a benefit.

Comment: @DanielMGessel in a supplier context, frequent rebuilds is certainly a good idea, if only because you need to be sure that you *can* do it any time you need to, and the only way to be sure of that is to do it frequently.

Comment: Compilers were continuously in development, both ours and theirs, and rebuilding everything validated changes. Between newly introduced compiler bugs and latent bugs being exposed, compiler changes could be destabilizing, but clean builds were always the gold standard.

Comment: @DanielMGessel : I almost certainly don't know the compilers your are referring to… I just remember gcc 3 -> 4 and gcc 4 -> 5… :-)

Comment: @StephenKitt : OK! d'better be safe than sorry, and since its not that much of a pain… rebuilt my libtool (apparently not concerned by debian fiddlings) Please update your answer with a possibility of concerns about libtool for non debian(like) distributions. I'll upvote & accept gratefully.

Comment: @MC68020 I added “Some tools do embed GCC paths, so you may want to rebuild those — this includes `libtool` in its default setup.” a few hours ago ;-).

Comment: @MC68020 I just looked at the gcc timeline; last time I messed with its source woulda been in the 1.30’s, when C++ was first being implemented…

Comment: @DanielMGessel : Another experience in industry context… under FDA regulations… whatever app rebuilt would have needed full re-validation… hopefully… I was old school, stay-low-tech… AND enjoying… 10 years guarantee & maintenance & support from suppliers… ;-) If it works… why fix it ? ;-)